# JavaFX Three-State Checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, eventhandler

**Given:**

I have a `javafx.scene.control.CheckBox` and I would like to allow 3-states instead of only 2 (`selected` and `not selected`).

I read about `indeterminate` state.

According to JavaDocs http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBox.html#allowIndeterminateProperty

> checked: indeterminate == false, checked == true
>
> unchecked: indeterminate == false, checked == false
>
> undefined: indeterminate == true

**Problem:**

I need to allow from `indeterminate` to `selected` only once

```
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox("Indeterminate");
    checkbox.setAllowIndeterminate(true);
    checkbox.setIndeterminate(true);
    checkbox.setSelected(false);
    checkbox.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                if (checkbox.isIndeterminate()) {
                    checkbox.setSelected(true);
                    checkbox.setIndeterminate(false);
                    checkbox.setAllowIndeterminate(false);
                    checkbox.setText("Checked");
                } else if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
                    checkbox.setSelected(false);
                    checkbox.setText("Unchecked");
                } else if (!checkbox.isSelected()) {
                    checkbox.setSelected(true);
                    checkbox.setText("Checked");
                }
            }
        });
```

Interestingly, when I click on the checkbox for the first time, it goes directly to the `else if (checkbox.isSelected())` block!!!

**Question:**

WHAT???! HOW? Why isn't this working?

What I need is that if it is initially indeterminate, then on the first click, it should become checked. And continue on more clicks: checked -> unchecked, unchecked -> checked, ...

Else if it initially not indeterminate (ie selected or not selected), then it should behave normally: checked -> unchecked, unchecked -> checked, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set [allowIndeterminateProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBox.html#allowIndeterminateProperty) to true, what you actually do is to allow the `CheckBox` to cycle all three states:

> Determines whether the user toggling the CheckBox should cycle through
>   all three states: checked, unchecked, and undefined. If true then all
>   three states will be cycled through; if false then only checked and
>   unchecked will be cycled.

In your case it should be set to false, as you want it just to cycle between *checked* and *unchecked*.

Then if you set [indeterminateProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBox.html#indeterminateProperty) **initially** either true or false the `CheckBox` will just cycle *checked* and *unchecked* states.

The reason why your `CheckBox` enters the **isSelected** branch is the cycle defined in the quote: *checked -> unchecked -> undefined -> checked -> ...*. Your `CheckBox` is in undefined state because of `checkbox.setIndeterminate(true);` and the next state is checked.

**Example**

This `CheckBox` is initially *undefined* then it cycles *checked* and *unchecked*.

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
checkBox.indeterminateProperty().set(true);
checkBox.setAllowIndeterminate(false);

checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if(newVal)
        System.out.println("Checked");
    else
        System.out.println("Unchecked");
});
```

Comment: well, you didn't the question properly. I want only ONCE to go from undefined to checked

Comment: Discussed with @rz3r0 in chat that he needed this solution.